# Bound on absolute value of a function containing $\Gamma(z)$ and $\zeta(z)$ function.

Tags: analysis, zeta-functions

Consider the following function :

> $$f(z)=\frac{e^{az}}{\Gamma(z)\zeta(bz)}$$
>
> $z=x+iy$

I want to know if $|f(z)|$ is bounded by $c/|z|^{1+\epsilon}$?

Where , $a,b,c;\epsilon > 0 $ are constants .

Also , It would be nice if we can tell the following limit exists or not ( and if exists the estimation ):

> $$\frac{ |f(z)|}{e^y}$$ as $y$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: On what domain. The reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)= \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$ tell us the decay of $\Gamma(z)$ on vertical lines. on $\Re(z) \ge \sigma > 1$ both $\zeta(z),1/\zeta(z)$ are bounded by $\zeta(\sigma)$.

Comment: $\zeta(z)$ has a lot of zeros...

Comment: @reuns thanks for reply . I'm looking for $x>1$ also consider  $b>1$

Comment: Then my comment above contains what you need. The answer is $|f(x+iy)| \le C_x (1+|y|)^{x/2} e^{y \pi /2}$. It is easy to show $\Gamma(x+iy)=\frac{\Gamma(x+iy+1) }{x+iy} \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$ so $f$ can be bounded on vertical lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: @reuns sir , if you don't mind , could you answer my other question on Abel plana summation please ??https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359413/on-series-of-mutually-inducing-doubts-about-infinite-series-in-context-of-ab